# Process.WaitForExit dinâmico

Tags: vb.net, thread, asynctask

Gostaria de saber se há algum jeito de saber se o processo saiu, mesmo continuando a execução do projeto.

Ao utilizar `Processo.WaitForExit` ele para o aplicativo, sua execução é parada.

Gostaria de saber se há um jeito de usar esse `WaitForExit`, mantendo a execução, exemplo:

```
Dim i As Process = New Process()
i.StartInfo.FileName = "Meu executável"
i.UseShellExecute = False
i.Start
i.WaitForExit

'Agora queria que o aplicativo funcionasse normalmente, sem que os botões fiquem congelados...
MsgBox("Aplicativo saiu.", 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto acontece porque ao utilizar o [método `Process.WaitForExit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), você o executa na [*thread* principal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b807sta6.aspx), que é o responsável por *redesenhar* a janela, receber mensagens, etc. O teu aplicativo continua em execução, porém não atualiza a janela, o que faz com que ela pareça estar *congelada*.

Para contornar este problema, você poderá criar o processo em outra [*thread*](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/creating-threads-in-vb.net), ou numa [pool de *threads*](http://www.dotnetperls.com/threadpool-vbnet), ou executar o processo de [modo paralelo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_paralela) usando a [biblioteca Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). Veja um exemplo deste último:

```
Public Sub executarArquivo(arquivo As String, argumentos As String)
    Dim processo As Process = New Process()
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = arquivo
    processo.StartInfo.Arguments = argumentos
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    processo.Start()

    processo.WaitForExit()
End Sub
```

Para chamar a função, faça assim:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       executarArquivo("Meu executável", "")
                   End Sub)

    MsgBox("Aplicativo saiu.", 0)
End Sub
```

Comment: Funcionou, valeu....